# How to run aws cli command on Google Cloud Function

Tags: google-app-engine, aws-cli

I have an access with aws.

Is this possible to do the following

1. Google Cloud Function can run aws-cli commands.
2. Google App Engine can kick actions of aws-cli commands.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import sys
import awscli.clidriver

def aws_demo(request):

    cmd = 'aws s3 ls'
    result = subprocess.run(
        cmd.split(" "),
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
    )

    print(result.stdout.decode())
    return str(result.stdout.decode())
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/bin/aws", line 19, in <module>
    import awscli.clidriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awscli'
```

Comment: Another option, instead of calling out to the AWS CLI, would be to incorporate the AWS SDK (boto3) into your Python program. This would allow the Python program to call the AWS API directly.

Answer (score 0):

> Google Cloud Function can run aws-cli commands?

The command-line AWS tools aren't available or installable in Google Cloud Functions. Your best bet is to use the [`boto3`](https://pypi.org/project/boto3/) Python package instead **as John suggested.**

As far as managing credentials within [`boto3`](https://pypi.org/project/boto3/) is concerned, there are a number of ways to configure credentials, as described [here.](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#configuring-credentials)

> Google App Engine can kick actions of aws-cli commands?

I think as with the Google Cloud Function, is not possible to run AWS command using the command line tool `awscli`.

I would highly recommend to also use [`boto3`](https://pypi.org/project/boto3/) as it will keep your infrastructure equal among the different GCP products.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for answered. But my requirement is different from use boto3. For example i want to run any command of aws cli etc.

Comment: As I mentioned before, the command line AWS tool is not available in Google Cloud Functions. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52693824/google-cloud-functions-how-do-i-authenticate-to-aws-s3-bucket) you will find a similar question related to this topic, and in fact the best solution is to use `boto3`. I hope it helps.

Comment: Okay i got it. Thank you very much 

Comment: Hello, Bilguun Altankhuyag. Do you mean your issue is solved with this answer? If so, could you please accept it so it has more visibility in the Stack Overflow Community?